# ignore local computer time and get date and time from timezone using momentjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to use `moment.js` to get the correct date and time of a user ignoring the date and time from the local computer which I'm thinking the user might change sometime. It's there a way to achieve this, I'm currently using the code below but it's not getting me the results I need

```
const datetime = moment().tz("America/Phoenix").format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss');
  console.log(datetime)
```

Comment: I think you il have to get it from an external service

Comment: The "best" way to prevent tinkering with the timestamp is probably to not submit a timestamp from the client at all. Instead use a server timestamp of when the request arrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way of doing this is using an external service to return a time that you want, either by creating an api yourself or using an existing one.

If you want something fast and easy you can try [TimeAPI](https://www.timeapi.io/).

```
GET https://www.timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timezone=America:Phoenix
```